# Is there a way to get Primefaces to add NONCE to more than one CSP directive

Tags: primefaces, content-security-policy

I'm using Primefaces 8.0.7.  My code use p:ajaxStatus:

```
<p:ajaxStatus class="25pix">
  <f:facet name="start">
    <p:graphicImage value="images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="complete">
    <h:outputText value="" />
  </f:facet>
</p:ajaxStatus>
```

However, at runtime, the f:facet element ends up with an inline style:

```
<td>
  <div id="j_idt26" class="25pix">
    <div id="j_idt26_start" style="display:none">
      <img id="j_idt27" src="images/ajaxloadingbar.gif?pfdrid_c=true" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="j_idt26_complete" style="display:none"></div>
  </div>
...
```

I have the CSP policy in my web.xml as:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CSP_POLICY</param-name>
    <param-value>style-src 'self';img-src 'self';connect-src 'self';frame-src 'self';font-src 'self';media-src 'self';object-src 'self';manifest-src 'self';form-action 'self';frame
-ancestors 'self';script-src 'self'</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I understand that Primefaces inserts the nonce to the end of the policy, but that only takes care of the script-src.  Is there a way I can get it to insert nonce on style-src too ?  Or is there a way I can get f:facet NOT to use inline style?

Thanks.

Comment: PrimeFaces only supports `script-src` in CSP and does not support every CSP option.  But since JS code is the most vulnerable to all aspects of CSP it should protect you. PrimeFaces makes heavy use of inline styles that is why it only currently supports JS.

Comment: Thanks.  Our OWASP ZAP scan is assigning this as a Medium risk.  Is it possible to add style-src protection in a future release of Primefaces?

Comment: It would take a MASSIVE refactoring of PrimeFaces to remove all inline styles from all components so I doubt it.  I will say did your Pen Tester try and exploit CSS vulnerability? Becuase its my understanding they can't exploit inline CSS without JS code and since our JS is protected it would be difficult/impossible for CSS to be exploited?